# FCKeditor changes '<' to '&lt;' and '>' to '&gt;' causing errors 

Tags: php, parsing, html-parsing, special-characters, fckeditor

**FCKeditor v2.6.6** changes input code containting `<` and `>` in it to `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively causing errors. Is there any way I can configure FCKeditor to parse these characters correctly otherwise they are entered into our database and incorrectly rendered when output in the PHP file.

Comment: I am using CKEditor4 with same problem!

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html

Check section for basicEntities. However, this is for CKEditor, FCKEditor might not have this. Maybe you should consider upgrading?

Otherwise, this might help: http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Configuration/Configuration_Options/ProcessHTMLEntities

Comment: Thanks jishi, I had JUST found this document and have changed the ProcessHTMLEntities to true (`FCKConfig.ProcessHTMLEntities = true`). I will test it.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I think the only way around this is `preg_replace` - I will write another question.